# Minimal style sheet for Excel Open XML with dates?

Tags: excel, date, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to create an Excel file using the Open XML SDK with the minimal style sheet needed that will allow me to format a cell as a date. Below is my attempt at a style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <x:cellXfs count="1">
        <x:xf numFmtId="14" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" />
    </x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

Even without referencing this style from a cell, Excel tells me that my file is corrupt. If I remove the cellXfs element, the file opens fine. Can someone explain what else I need to add to this? The C# code that creates the style sheet is below.

```
var stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
var cellFormats = new CellFormats() { Count = 1 };
var cellFormat = new CellFormat();
cellFormat.NumberFormatId = 14;
cellFormat.FormatId = 0;
cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true);
cellFormats.Append(cellFormat);
stylesheet.Append(cellFormats);
```

I've tried adding in cell style formats and cell styles, but just having the above seems to break the document and I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Through a lot of trial and error, I've found that a style sheet needs the following:

- Default font
- Default fill
- Default border
- Default cell format

Leaving any of those out will cause Excel to error, unless all of them are left out. In addition, I added another cell format for the date.

I hope this is useful to someone else. The following code creates a working style sheet that allows for a date format (number format id 22):

```cs
var stylesheet = new Stylesheet();

// Default Font
var fonts = new Fonts() { Count = 1, KnownFonts = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) };
var font = new Font
                {
                    FontSize = new FontSize() { Val = 11 },
                    FontName = new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" },
                    FontFamilyNumbering = new FontFamilyNumbering() { Val = 2 },
                    FontScheme = new FontScheme() { Val = new EnumValue<FontSchemeValues>(FontSchemeValues.Minor) }
                };
fonts.Append(font);
stylesheet.Append(fonts);

// Default Fill
var fills = new Fills() { Count = 1 };
var fill = new Fill();
fill.PatternFill = new PatternFill() { PatternType = new EnumValue<PatternValues>(PatternValues.None) };
fills.Append(fill);
stylesheet.Append(fills);

// Default Border
var borders = new Borders() { Count = 1 };
var border = new Border
                    {
                        LeftBorder = new LeftBorder(),
                        RightBorder = new RightBorder(),
                        TopBorder = new TopBorder(),
                        BottomBorder = new BottomBorder(),
                        DiagonalBorder = new DiagonalBorder()
                    };
borders.Append(border);
stylesheet.Append(borders);

// Default cell format and a date cell format
var cellFormats = new CellFormats() { Count = 2 };

var cellFormatDefault = new CellFormat { NumberFormatId = 0, FormatId = 0, FontId = 0, BorderId = 0, FillId = 0 };
cellFormats.Append(cellFormatDefault);

var cellFormatDate = new CellFormat { NumberFormatId = 22, FormatId = 0, FontId = 0, BorderId = 0, FillId = 0, ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) };
cellFormats.Append(cellFormatDate);

stylesheet.Append(cellFormats);

return stylesheet;
```

The resulting XML looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <x:fonts count="1" x14ac:knownFonts="1" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
        <x:font>
            <x:sz val="11" />
            <x:name val="Calibri" />
            <x:family val="2" />
            <x:scheme val="minor" />
        </x:font>
    </x:fonts>
    <x:fills count="1">
        <x:fill>
            <x:patternFill patternType="none" />
        </x:fill>
    </x:fills>
    <x:borders count="1">
        <x:border>
            <x:left />
            <x:right />
            <x:top />
            <x:bottom />
            <x:diagonal />
        </x:border>
    </x:borders>
    <x:cellXfs count="2">
        <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
        <x:xf numFmtId="22" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" />
    </x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

Comment: I found that it should have _two_ fill patterns by default, the other one being `<fill><patternFile patternTyle="gray125"></fill>`. It doesn't give an error if you don't provide this, but nonetheless if you try to provide your own fill pattern at ID 1 it will not work.

Comment: And 13 years later, you helped me resolve an issue I've been trying to figure out most of the day!

Comment: It is one full day I lost tracking down the issue and spotting your answer here, almost 8 years later. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Brian. This answer still helping people in 2023 :)